# How to increase aws ec2 load balancer size limit, my post request return 413

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb, payload, http-status-code-413

I am calling a POST method at an EC2 instance from a Lambda function with a big size json payload, the size of this payload is around 1.6MB. The response returned 413(payload too large). The response message is like
`http://{dns_id}.elb.us-east-4.amazonaws.com:80 \"POST /endpoint/payload HTTP/1.1\" 413 176`

How can I increase the request body limit to solve this issue?

Thank you

searched on google, but no useful approach

Comment: 1.6MB should be fine both for the lambda as well as the LB, unless you are doing an async lambda invocation but that would make little sense (not even sure it is possible). Does the lambda not even receive the request?

Comment: @luk2302 sorry for confusing you. I am going to call an endpoint at EC2 instance from a lambda function.